# Sending video file stored in mongodb using flask does not allow for scrubbing and does not work on mobile

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a flask app that retrieves a video file from a mongodb database stored using fsgrid. I then send this file to the user. However the problem is that on chrome (desktop) the video will not let me scrub or fast forward. And on mobile, videos just won't play, they return a grey screen. I have seen people with similar problems: like [this (fix)](https://gist.github.com/psi-4ward/7099001) for nodejs and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/b4oueu/serve_videos_with_flask_on_mobile/) where its is recommended to send a binary file (which I do). I have looked and can't find anyone using flask where they are encountering this problem. This leads me to believe I have done something wrong. Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/view/<postid>')
def Rview(postid):
    ...
    post_id_obj = ObjectId(postid)
    cur_post = col_posts.find_one({"_id": post_id_obj}) # gets entry that matches the id
    location = cur_post['file'] # gets the fsgrid location of the file
    file_mimetype = cur_post['mimetype']
    file_ext =  '.' + file_mimetype.split("/")[1]
    return send_file(BytesIO(fs.get(location).read()), mimetype=file_mimetype, as_attachment=False, attachment_filename=(str(random.randint(10000000,99999999)) + file_ext)) # sends file along with a random file name
```

not sure if this is needed but html

```
<video class="video" controls>
    <source src="/view/{{ location }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I am also using nginx on the production server if that helps

EDIT:

This also might be important I encode/compress the videos like this
`ffmpeg -i -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -c:a copy`. After this I also reduce the quality a bit.

Comment: How large are the files?  Scrubbing and fast forward don't work until the entire file is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for helping! @TimRoberts it does it for any size file. I have tried it with compressed 5 second long videos, still won't scrub.